# Write Serialization for Cache Coherence in the presence of Store Buffers

Tags: computer-architecture, concurrency, cpu-cache

One of the requirements for a coherent memory system is write serialization - "two writes to address X by any two processors are observed in the same order by all processors". I am not sure how this condition would be met when the CPU cores have a store buffer into which stores are retired before updating the memory hierarchy.

Suppose Cores A and B both retire a store to address X (which is cached by both A and B), and these stores are now in the store buffers and are yet to update the cache. Now loads from address X on both cores A and B could retire after obtaining the load value from the store buffers ie loads from X on core A see value written by the store to X on core A, similarly, loads from X on core B see value written by the store to X on core B. Say now, the store to X from core A sends a read-upgrade message to core B. What happens next on core B? After coherence transactions have completed for A, the store to X on B updates the local cache. After the stores to X from A and B have completed the final value of X is the store by B.

Above, the order for values seen by A for X are write by A followed by the write to B. But this doesn't seem to be the order seen by B. So the question is how is write serialization enforced when store buffers are being used?

(This is based on my understand of the various material I have read and would appreciate it if anyone can point to sources that discuss these issues in detail)

Comment: 1) Please use some formatting -- paragraphs, mostly -- to make your post more readable. 2) Which source are you citing from there?

Comment: You may use cache coherency mechanisms to prevent several cores from simultaneously writing at the same address. For example, with MESI, if two CPUs have the same address in a "shared state" cache line, the first CPU to attempt the write will trigger the invalidation of the cache line in the other CPU.

Answer (score 7):

From a *coherence* perspective, I think your example is coherent.  All processors believe that the write and read from A happened first, then the write and read from B happened later.

From a *consistency* standpoint you need to be more careful.  (Consistency is the global ordering of memory operations to *different* addresses.) The way consistency is handled in practice is that the store buffer sits before retirement, not after.  The store buffer acts as a little coherent cache for the speculative memory state.  A store instruction is not permitted to retire until its processor has acquired write ownership of the appropriate cache line.

The store buffer needs to be aware of all the coherence traffic reaching the cache.  If a speculative load gets its value from the store buffer, but the corresponding memory location is invalidated before the load retires, the load (and everything following it in the reorder-buffer) needs to be squashed and reexecuted.

Comment: In the above, B disagrees with A on the order in which the two writes to X happen, so it's not a coherent example.

Comment: Many store buffers are actually occupied on both sides of retirement. The buffer entry may be allocated before retirement, but at some point the store instruction may retire, even if the data in the store buffer cannot commit to cache (e.g., because the line isn't present in L1, for example). Now the store lives only in the store buffer and is not speculative, but hasn't reached the cache yet. The CPU will ensure that it is eventually committed - if something serializing like an interrupt occurs, these store buffer entries are maintained.

Comment: From the point of view of the outside world, the total write order is that of the store buffer entries committing to cache (more precisely, the order in which their RFO requests are granted as seen by the external bus), which is interesting because it happens after the store instruction itself is "retired"!

Answer (score 5):

Situations like the one you describe are the reason why processor manuals for architectures with store buffers such as intel tend to state that two stores by cores *i* and *j* are seen in the same order by all *other* cores.

Common techniques for enforcing sequential consistency for certain memory locations include *fence instructions* and *bus locking*. How these techniques work exactly depends somewhat on the architecture. How they work in principle is described in modern textbooks such as [Michael L Scott's *Shared-Memory Synchronization*](http://dx.doi.org/10.2200/S00499ED1V01Y201304CAC023). Details for architectures are contained in the manufacturers' handbooks. For instance, Intel publishes [4,670p software developer manuals](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf) that describe what they think they are doing. (This does of course include much more but I'm not aware of any other comprehensive source.) Scientists who try to prove anything about the behaviour of their programs when running on Intel's x86 or ARM nowadays are rather fond of the formalisations Peter Sewell et. al. in Cambridge (UK) produced. These are still abstractions of what's really going on but they do model store buffers and their effect. These formalisations have been experimentally verified. For a start I'd recommend their [Communication of the ACM 2010 paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1785414.1785443). More can be found at [his web page](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/weakmemory/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and welcome to CS.SE!  Can you edit your answer to be a bit more explicit about how this answers the question?  The question was "how is write serialization enforced...?"  Are you saying the answer is "typically write serialization is only enforced for the other cores, but is not enforced for cores A or B"?  I want to be sure whether I've understood you correctly.

Comment: @D.W. sorry, I had conveniently overlooked the actual question to focus on one particular point. I hope this is now fixed. To answer your question, yes, modern architectures do not guarantee sequential consistency for ordinary writes to memory. That's why they have various mechanisms to enforce SC for selected memory locations. They do so for performance reasons. For instance, the currently best-performing garbage collectors for JVMs exploit this.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is this: Store buffers make the memory system fast and inconsistent.

Consider a file system that always does the right thing; a write to a file is immediately visible to all others, and that it handles concurrent writes from multiple clients correctly. Everyone can see the writes serialized. It is a strongly consistent file system.

Now imagine that the programmer creates a convenience library that buffers all writes, and periodically delivers them to the file system. This works just fine if the file is not shared. There is no inconsistency if there is no other viewer. But it is clearly a problem if the file is shared, and it is not the file system's fault. Adding buffering messed it up.

If you treat the convenience library as the interface between the file system and your program (in effect, the API *is* the file system for all you care), then all you see is an inconsistent file system. On the other hand, if you know about the buffering, and if the API provides a sync() call where it waits until the buffers are drained, then a write(X); sync() combination on one client and a write(Y); sync() combination on another client is equivalent to having made calls to the underlying API. We are back to regaining consistency, at the expense of waiting.

In your question, the cache coherent memory is the file system, the store buffer is the user-side buffer, and the sync() call is an mfence or equivalent "barrier" instruction.

The cache coherence protocol (MESI) is strongly consistent (linearizable), but requires coordination, which can suck out performance. We know that most memory (95% or more) is never shared with another process, so why make the CPU wait unnecessarily for all accesses? Hence store buffering and no fences required.

However, for those cases where it is absolutely imperative that we need strong consistency (updates to shared memory addresses), then the program must issue a fence instruction. In higher-level languages like C++ and Java, there are several constructs and qualifiers (synchronised, volatile, final) that introduce these fences at the right moments. But if you mistakenly omit to use one of these facilities, prepare to spend a long time figuring out what happened. This is what makes shared memory concurrent programming so error-prone. And this is why Java programmers should know about store buffers.